# Juniper - minor host 0 /var partition usage is high

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex, syslog

Currently running a EX4300 switch. We seem to be low on space on fpc0.

I have already run the request system storage cleanup all-members (only cleaned up a few megabytes).

I have cleared the WTMP file which cleared 20 - 30mb.

I am now looking to clear more space.

Ran the df -h command from the shell to give you an idea that the /var partition is currently sitting at 90% usage.

```
root@Core:RE:0% df -h
Filesystem       Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/da0s1a      340M    129M    183M    41%    /
devfs            1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/md0          68M     68M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jbase
/dev/md1         5.8M    1.1M    4.2M    21%    /packages/mfs-fips-mode-powerpc
/dev/md2         2.9M    2.9M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/fips-mode-powerpc-12.3R3.4
/dev/md3         9.0M    4.4M    3.9M    53%    /packages/mfs-jcrypto-ex
/dev/md4          12M     12M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jcrypto-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/md5         8.1M    3.5M    4.0M    47%    /packages/mfs-jdocs-ex
/dev/md6         6.2M    6.2M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jdocs-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/md7          43M     39M    718K    98%    /packages/mfs-jkernel-ex
/dev/md8         107M    107M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jkernel-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/md9          12M    7.9M    3.6M    69%    /packages/mfs-jpfe-ex45x
/dev/md10         22M     22M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jpfe-ex45x-12.3R3.4
/dev/md11         17M     12M    3.2M    79%    /packages/mfs-jroute-ex
/dev/md12         38M     38M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jroute-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/md13         12M    7.2M    3.6M    66%    /packages/mfs-jswitch-ex
/dev/md14         21M     21M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jswitch-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/md15         14M    9.5M    3.4M    73%    /packages/mfs-jweb-ex
/dev/md16         25M     25M      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4
/dev/da0s3e      239M    201M     19M    91%    /var
/dev/md17        126M     78K    116M     0%    /tmp
/dev/da0s3d      702M    132K    646M     0%    /var/tmp
/dev/da0s4d      116M    644K    106M     1%    /config
/dev/md18        118M     24M     84M    22%    /var/rundb
procfs           4.0K    4.0K      0B   100%    /proc
/var/jail/etc    239M    201M     19M    91%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4/jail/var/etc
/var/jail/run    239M    201M     19M    91%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4/jail/var/run
/var/jail/tmp    239M    201M     19M    91%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4/jail/var/tmp
/var/tmp         702M    132K    646M     0%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4/jail/var/tmp/uploads
devfs            1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /packages/mnt/jweb-ex-12.3R3.4/jail/dev
```

When running the du -h /var/ command from the shell, none of the folders show any large usage.

```
root@Core:RE:0% du -h /var/
2.0K    /var/.snap
2.0K    /var/bin
4.0K    /var/crash
2.0K    /var/cron/tabs
4.0K    /var/cron
2.0K    /var/db/certs/common/key-pair
2.0K    /var/db/certs/common/local
2.0K    /var/db/certs/common/certificate-request
2.0K    /var/db/certs/common/certification-authority
2.0K    /var/db/certs/common/crl
 12K    /var/db/certs/common
4.0K    /var/db/certs/system-key-pair
4.0K    /var/db/certs/system-cert
 22K    /var/db/certs
2.0K    /var/db/commit-queue
2.0K    /var/db/persistent_mac
2.0K    /var/db/dhcp_snoop
306K    /var/db/help
2.0K    /var/db/fsad
2.0K    /var/db/entropy
2.0K    /var/db/ext
2.0K    /var/db/gtpcd
2.0K    /var/db/leases
2.0K    /var/db/zoneinfo
392K    /var/db
4.0K    /var/etc/filters
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl-/local
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl-/peer
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl-/certificate-authority
8.0K    /var/etc/ssl-
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl/local
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl/peer
2.0K    /var/etc/ssl/certificate-authority
8.0K    /var/etc/ssl
204K    /var/etc
2.0K    /var/home/admin/.ssh
4.0K    /var/home/admin
6.0K    /var/home
2.0K    /var/log/flowc/failed
4.0K    /var/log/flowc
2.0K    /var/log/ext
2.0K    /var/log/ggsn/gtppcdr
4.0K    /var/log/ggsn
2.2M    /var/log
2.0K    /var/run/ext
2.0K    /var/run/named
2.0K    /var/run/ppp
192K    /var/run
2.0K    /var/sw/pkg
4.0K    /var/sw
2.0K    /var/tmp/.snap
2.0K    /var/tmp/gres-tp
2.0K    /var/tmp/rtsdb
8.0K    /var/tmp
2.0K    /var/empty
2.0K    /var/account
2.0K    /var/at/jobs
2.0K    /var/at/spool
6.0K    /var/at
2.0K    /var/backups
2.0K    /var/transfer/config
4.0K    /var/transfer
2.0K    /var/heimdal
100K    /var/jail/etc
4.0K    /var/jail/run
2.0K    /var/jail/tmp/uploads
 14K    /var/jail/tmp
120K    /var/jail
2.0K    /var/mail
2.0K    /var/msgs
2.0K    /var/named
2.0K    /var/preserve
2.0K    /var/validate
2.0K    /var/logical-systems
2.0K    /var/rwho
2.0K    /var/spool/lock
2.0K    /var/spool/lpd
2.0K    /var/spool/mqueue
2.0K    /var/spool/opielocks
2.0K    /var/spool/output/lpd
4.0K    /var/spool/output
 14K    /var/spool
2.0K    /var/yp
2.0K    /var/rundb/.snap
2.0K    /var/rundb/private
 10K    /var/rundb/sdb/shmem
520K    /var/rundb/sdb
 24M    /var/rundb
2.0K    /var/etcroot/ssh
 98K    /var/etcroot
2.0K    /var/mfs/var/tmp
 86K    /var/mfs/var/shmipc/if-rtsdb
 88K    /var/mfs/var/shmipc
 92K    /var/mfs/var
 94K    /var/mfs
4.0K    /var/root/.ssh
 10K    /var/root
 27M    /var/
```

Im struggling to find any other places under /var where there could be files that could be deleted

Comment: /var/tmp/ is really the only place you need to be concerned about day-to-day.  Are you seeing some kind of issue?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like after taking the issue up with JTAC support, the /var partition was misrepresenting the amount of space that was actually in use. We haven't rebooted our switch in the last four years as it is our main core switch. As per JTAC, the reboot resolved the issue and the /var partition now reflects only 2% of the space is used.